# Assinging QVector in structure to contents of QVector in main

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I have a structure :

```
struct node
{
    QPoint position;
    QVector<node> neighbours;

    void add(QPoint);
    void addNeighbours(QVector<node>);

    ...
};
```

With methods :

```
void node::add(QPoint p)
{
    position = p;
}

void node::addNeighbours(QVector<node> n)
{
    neighbours = n;
}
```

However when I try to use *addNeighbours* I get the following error :

```
error: C2662: 'node::addNeighbours' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const node' to 'node &'
Conversion loses qualifiers
```

From looking online I think the solution comes from; using the correct pointers and possibly by the `QVectors::Iterator()`. Although I cannot come up with a solution, any pointer in the right direction or an explanation on why this is happening is greatly appreciated.

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QVector<node> map;
    QVector<node> tmp;
    node n;

    //Populate map
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3;  j++)
        {
            n.add(QPoint(i,j));
            map.append(n);
        }

    //Add required nodes to tmp
    tmp.append(map.at(1));
    tmp.append(map.at(3));

    //Set the neighbour nodes of map(0) using tmp vector
    map.at(0).addNeighbours(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
map.at(0).addNeighbours(tmp); // at() : returns a const reference
```

To

```
map[0].addNeighbours(tmp); // [] : returns a non-const reference
```

Also, it's better to change `addNeighbours` to this:

```
 void node::addNeighbours(const QVector<node> &n)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I didn't even think about changing it as you said - I was focused on how the data was transferred via the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

QVector::at() provides only read-only access, see the documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvector.html#at

This means that you can only call methods that are declared as "const".

addNeighbours() can't be const, however, because it modifies the object.

So what you need to do is to access the object in a different way, so you don't get a const reference:

```
map[0].addNeighbours(tmp);
```

Comment: Overlooked checking QVector::at() in the documentation, only QVector::operator=, thanks for the explanation